# Boost::serialization and base/derived relationship not registered

Tags: boost-serialization

I have 2 polymorphic types that are derived from like so:

```
class Base1 {...};
class Base2 {...};
class Derived1 : public Base1 {...};
class Derived : public Derived1, public Base2 {};
```

I use

```
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(Derived)
```

in the serialization header file for derived. and

```
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(Derived)
```

for the translation unit implementing the serialize free function for Derived, which simply call base_object for both bases. I do this for NONE of Base1, Base2, Derived1.
I only instantiate the serialize function for archives required for boost::mpi.
All this is in a shared object that is linked in to generate the executable.

Saving to the archive fails when I use a Base1* pointer.

While debugging, i see in

```
boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp
```

that around line 393, the derived type is properly registered, but the exception is thrown just a little later at 411 where it says

```
"the base/derived relationship hasn't be registered"
```

and the exception shows the types

```
Derived
```

and

```
Base1
```

How can I register the relationship itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I had actually missed to call base_object in the implemenation of serialize for Derived1.

now it works like a charm,